# Get default value of radio button without change in jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have created radio buttons in html.

I have tried to get default value, which is a in this case.

What I want to have is to get a default value without any click because it is default.

Here is what I have tried.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#radios").click(function() {
  rad_val = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();
  alert(rad_val);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radios" id="radios">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" checked value="a">                  
       <label>A</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="b">                                                
       <label>B</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="c">                          
       <label>C</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="d">
       <label>D</label>
</div>
```

From this code, I can get radio value if I click a button.

However, I don't get a default value when I load the page.

How can I get a default value without any button clicked.

Comment: Define the `rad_val` variable upon page load, outside of the `click` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same code in the click event listener as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     let rad_val = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();
     alert(rad_val);
     $("#radios").click(function() {
          rad_val = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();
          alert(rad_val);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radios" id="radios">
     <input type="radio" name="radio" checked value="a">                  
     <label>A</label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio" value="b">                                      <label>B</label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio" value="c">                          
     <label>C</label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio" value="d">
     <label>D</label>
</div>
```

P.S.: you had a syntax mistake (missing `{`).

Answer (score 0):

Hello There is a minor mistake in your code. See updated code that will also give you selected radio button value on page load

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            rad_val = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();
            alert(rad_val);
            $("#radios").click(function() {
                rad_val = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();
                alert(rad_val);
            });
        });
</script>
```